# Understanding reduce with enumerate for a list of lists

Tags: python, list, reduce, enumerate

I am trying to multiply the first number, 1, of the first list, the second number of the second list, 5, and so on for a list of lists. For example,  for [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]], I'd like to get 1*5*9.

While there are many possible ways to do this, I wondered how reduce does with enumerate:

```
def test(m):
    return reduce(lambda a, b: a[1][a[0]]*b[1][b[0]], enumerate(m))

print test([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])
```

I would think that `a` in the beginning is (0, [1,2,3]) so that a[1] is [1,2,3], and a[0] is 0, and so a[1][a[0]] is 1.

However, I get the following exception:

```
return reduce(lambda a, b: a[1][a[0]]*b[1][b[0]], enumerate(mat))
TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Why is `a` integer?

Comment: Not at all sure what you are trying to do - enumerating a list would give you index and value (if you want to do something with the index). Otherwise no need to 'enumerate'. So I guess there's problem with that. So from your input - it's absolutely not clear what you are trying to do. If you want to multiple something in lists, please be clear what your input and expected output is. Unfortunately your post is a mix of questions and experiments - rendering impossible to understand what you are trying to do!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your final and intermediate values are simple integers. So you should start with `1`, and then lambda will always get an integer as `a`, namely the product so far. And `b` will be the next enumerated item. So here's how to do it:

```
>>> reduce(lambda a, b: a * b[1][b[0]],
           enumerate([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7,8,9]]), 1)
45
```

Python 2 still allows this, btw:

```
>>> reduce(lambda a, (i, b): a * b[i],
           enumerate([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7,8,9]]), 1)
45
```

Comment: What I wanted to do (just for practice) was more like the product of diagonal elements of a square matrix using a list of lists like I said in my original post. So, what I am after is 1*5*9 for the particular case. While there are many other ways to do it (e.g., using for loops), I chose to use enumerate to index the diagonal element, but stuck with the behavior that I didn't expect. The example with 2 tuples worked as I expected: it produced 5 (=1*5) and it should be an integer.

Comment: Ah darn, I misunderstood. Check the top of my now updated answer. The rest is still somewhat valid, so I'll leave it there for now.

Comment: @JustDoIt And now I actually changed the whole thing :-)

Comment: Thanks, your comment 'Your final and intermediate values are simple integers' definitely clears my mind up. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @JustDoIt Yeah, `a` being integer was really the only part you missed. You had all the harder parts right :-)

Comment: @Stefan Pochmann I tried to rewrite your answer in a more readable way. Please check it out.

Comment: @LimH. Already saw it and I just find it really convoluted, sorry. I wish Python 3 would still allow the Python 2 syntax I added to my answer now (you made me think of that :-).

Comment: Cheers. I actually didn't know that syntax :D

Comment: @LimH. I only learned about it recently as well. And then I was immediately disappointed that Py3 had thrown it out :-(

Answer (score 1):

So since you're trying to reach  a final value of the diagonal numbers multiplied together this is how O'd do it:

**Example:**

```
def idiagonal(xs_of_ys):
    for i, x in enumerate(xs_of_ys):
        for j, y in enumerate(x):
            if i == j:
                yield y


print reduce(lambda x, y: x * y, idiagonal(xs), 1)  # prints 45
```

Comment: This is not what I want to do. I want to multiply 1*5*9 for the particular example, as I said in the original post, which I use the enumerate to choose the numbers (first number in the first list, the second number in the second list, and so on.)

Answer (score 0):

From what you explained in one of the comments - you are trying to multiply the diagonal elements of a matrix and now I understand why you want to 'enumerate' - that's indeed correct 'cos you want to get that index. So following code would do that for you.

First map gets all the required elements in a list and the reduce then multiplies them to the desired value. Note: a couple of caveats, enumerate gives you out a tuple, so you've to add it as (x,y) in the map lambda.

```
a = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
reduce(lambda p,q: p*q, map(lambda (x,y): y[x], enumerate(a)), 1)
```

or

```
reduce(lambda p,q: p*q, [y[x] for (x,y) in enumerate(a)], 1)
```

Edit: Added a list comprehension version instead of map-lambda.

Note the list comprehension version is just about as fast as the above answer (only about 10% slower), for readability, I'd trade that.

Comment: I just tried to timeit this answer with @Stefan Pochman's answer. As expected the answer above is about 50% slower to @Stefan Pochman's answer - which is intuitively expected (list build up in map), but not way slower - that I thought. Personally I find this lot more readable than say `x[1][x[0]] `, but that's a matter of taste.

Answer (score 0):

Even though Stefan's answer is perfect in functionality, I'd like to point out that ... we are not the compiler, you know. There is no preventing us from writing something more readable that even illustrates what you are trying to do without explaining a thing:

```
from collections import namedtuple
Row = namedtuple('Row', ['num', 'columns'])

m = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
reduce(lambda result, row: result * row.columns[row.num], 
       (Row(*data) for data in enumerate(m)), 1)
```

Looking at the reduce function, now we know that you want to accumulate on the item at column number = row number. If that doesn't spell diagonal, I don't know what does :)